# Combining transitions in d3

Tags: d3.js

How can a second transitions be added to an ongoing transition in D3 without interrupting the first one? I created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dakabipaju/1/edit?html,js,output) to illustrate the problem. In the example one button triggers a transition to increase the width of a rectangle and the other button triggers a transition to turn its fill red.

```
function changeFill() {
  d3.select("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(4000)
    .style("fill", "red");  
}

function changeSize(){
  d3.select("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(4000)
    .attr("width","300");
}
```

If the two buttons are pressed consecutively (the second one is pressed before the end of first transition) the second transition interrupts the ongoing first one. How is it possible to combine the two transitions to allow both of them to end in the desired end points?

Comment: This might be of interest to you - https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5348789

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just name your transitions. By giving your transitions different names, the same element can have different transitions without the last transition cancelling the first transition.

```js
function changeFill() {
  d3.select("rect")
    .transition("transition1")//name here
    .duration(5000)
    .style("fill", "red");

}

function changeSize(){
  d3.select("rect")
    .transition("transition2")//different name here
    .duration(5000)
    .attr("width","300");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeFill()">Change fill</button>
<button onclick="changeSize()">Change size</button>
<p>
<svg width="500" height="150">
  <rect width="30" height="30"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was as easy as I hoped it would be.